# How to rename a blob file in Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I want to rename an existing file in Azure Storage Explorer.

the command bar has many buttons: copy, paste, clone, delete, etc.
rename is not one of them.

[image]

the context menu does not have rename either
[image]

Comment: I think you cannot rename blobs in Storage. You need to create a copy with the new name and then delete the old one.

Comment: You can use "Clone" option to create a copy of the existing blob with new name and then delete the old blob.

Answer (score 1):

> How to rename a blob file?

I agree with Juunas's comment you cannot rename blobs in Storage Explorer directly.

Instead, you can use the below code with package **`azure.storage.blob`** which copies the file with the new name and deletes the old blob file using Python SDK.

In my environment, I have a blob with an image file name **`goodone.jpg`**

**Portal:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


connection_string = "Your-storage-connection string"
container_name = "test"    
        
file_name="goodone.jpg"
new_file_name="sample123.jpg"

client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)

new_blob_client=container_client.get_blob_client(new_file_name) 
new_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(blob_client.url)

blob_client.delete_blob()
print("The file is Renamed successfully:",{new_file_name})
```

**Output:**

```
The file is Renamed successfully: {'sample123.jpg'}
```

[image]

**Portal:**

The above code executed and renamed the blob file successfully.

[image]